# LOG4J2 Use multiple config files using java

Tags: java, config, log4j2

can log4j2 use multiple config files. I wanna run my project and load one default config file - logger.xml and after that to check if there is a second configuration from another file logger_1.xml and to add it and not to override the first one. 
Here is some dummy code. In short I wanna fill up the arrayList with file paths and then to load all of them.

```
  public class LoggerConfiguratorManager
{
public static final String LOG4J_PATH = "etc/confs/logger.xml";

  private static LoggerContext context = null;
  private static final ConfigurationFactory factory =  XmlConfigurationFactory.getInstance();
  private static ConfigurationSource configurationSource = null;
  private static Configuration configuration = null;
  private static final ArrayList<String> registred_logger = new ArrayList<>();

  private static void loadLoggerConfig(String logger_path)
  {
    InputStream is = null;
    try
    {
      if(logger_path.endsWith(".xml"))
        is = new FileInputStream(logger_path);
      else
      {
        final ZipFile archive = new ZipFile(logger_path);
        final ZipEntry logger_entry = archive.getEntry(LOG4J_PATH);
        if(logger_entry == null) throw new IOException("Cannot find 'logger.xml' in " + logger_path);
        is = archive.getInputStream(logger_entry);
      }

      configurationSource = new ConfigurationSource(is);
      configuration = factory.getConfiguration(configurationSource);
    }
    catch(IOException ex)
    {
      System.err.println("=============================================================================");
      System.err.println("=============================== LOGGER CONFIG ===============================");
      System.err.println("=============================================================================");
      System.err.println("=== [ERROR] " + ex);
    }
    finally
    {
      if (configurationSource != null)
      {
        context = Configurator.initialize(null, configurationSource);
        context.start(configuration);
        try { is.close(); } catch(IOException ex) { }
      }
    }
  }

  public static void load()
  {
    registred_logger.add(Globals.getClassLocation(LoggerConfiguratorManager.class));

    for(final String conf : registred_logger)
      loadLoggerConfig(conf);
  }

  public static void regLoggerConf(String conf_path) { registred_logger.add(conf_path); }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest doing instead:

```
  public class LoggerConfiguratorManager {

     private static final String LOG4J_PATH = "etc/confs/log4j2.xml";
     private static final StringBuffer paths = new StringBuffer(LOG4J_PATH);

     public static void registerConfiguration(String confPath) {
         paths.append(",").append(confPath);
     }

     public static void initLog4j() {
         Configurator.initializer("My Config", null, paths.toString(), null);
     }
  }
```

For a full working example please see https://github.com/rgoers/CompositeConfigurationExample.

Comment: this works but in one of my cases the file is inside another program i.e. inside a jar archive ant this doesn't help me :( any other suggestion.

Comment: How are you finding the file then?

Comment: you can see my code above. I first get the path of the current class file and then use ZipEntry and get the whole logger.xml into InputStream

Comment: So if I am reading this right you have a list of jars that you somehow create. You then look at each of those jars looking for a log4j configuration.  If you could either a) use ClassLoader.getResources(LOG4J_PATH) to create a list of URIs to pass to Configurator.initialize or, if you for some reason only want to be limited to a specific set of jars, b) specify the path to the configs in the jars as URIs and pass that lists to Configurator.initialize() then I believe you would get what you want.

Comment: Not working again :( if I add only one path to the StringBuffer then it's work like a charm using ClassLoader.getResources(). But when I add a second config it's go back to not working stage. 
Is there any special option that must be on inside the config file to make this work. I also tried with List<URI> and with two files that are outside the jar archive but without any luck.

Comment: What do your configuration files look like?

Comment: first conf - http://pastebin.com/knbNapU1
second conf - http://pastebin.com/UmHjKUZk
I've tried with and without two root logger no diff. One by one they both work fine...

Comment: Please change your configurations to specify status="trace" and post the log that results from that. Also, when you say they don't work what exactly does that mean? Do you get an exception or is stuff not being properly logged or are the files not created?  Also, what version of Lo4j2 are you using?

Comment: The only error is this : ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.
They only appear in console, there no log files created. All the logs are just list into the console from where i started the application.  If i use only one of the above config file, lets says the first one - it create 3 files - dolphin.log sys.log and xlang.log with different log information, like it supposed to be.
Nothing different happens when I changed status to trace :(

Comment: Please see the link in the answer above to the github project I created.